# tcpdump - regex to do validation on a filter

Tags: regex, validation, filter, tcpdump

Looking for a way to make sure a string is a valid tcpdump filter, for example -

```
host 192.168.254.36 and host 192.168.205.4
```

Is there a way to validate the string? using a regex or something?

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a way to validate the string?*

Yes, there is.  I think the easiest way is to run `tcpdump -d` and let `tcpdump` validate the capture filter for you.  Refer to the [`tcpdump` man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) for more details.

If you don't care about the packet-matching BPF code itself, you can simply redirect the output to `/dev/null` and just look at the return code, for example:

A valid capture filter:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -d icmp &> /dev/null
echo $?
0
```

An invalid capture filter:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -d foo &> /dev/null
echo $?
1
```

I'll note also that [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) supports the `-d` option as well.

Comment: Are you sure `dumpcap -d` works the same way as tcpdump version? When I tried it out, even on intentional bad filters, it doesn't error out and the output looks same as good filter (when you don't pipe output to /dev/null). I wish it worked the same.

Comment: Yes, `dumpcap -d` works.  Try `dumpcap -i eth0 -f icmp -d` vs `dumpcap -i eth0 -f foo -d`.  Refer to the [dumpcap man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) for more information on `dumpcap` options.

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I forgot that with dumpcap, you have to prepend -f for the filter string whereas tcpdump you don't

Answer (score 0):

I just guess you are looking for a Regex for your IP-Address?:

```
'\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4}\b'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the thing is, the filter could be a lot of other things besides ip, also port etc.